# Python 2.7.3 - Function not returning the right values in a string formatted table

Tags: python

Here's the current code for my Black Jack game:

```
import random
def showMenu():
    userInput = raw_input("Welcome to the game of Black Jack! Please choose an option from the following: \n - Start Game \n - Rules \n - Exit")
    if userInput == "Start Game":
        return maingame()

def maingame():
    done = False
    return cardGenerator()
    print "{0:>4} {01:>18} {02:>20} {03:>18}".format("Player Money", (cards[0], cards[1]), "CPU Cards", "CPU Money")

def getInitialMoney():
    initialdough = 5000

def cardGenerator():
    #Assign a random suit
    suit_card = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
    from random import choice
    #Assign a random number between 1-13 (Ace to King)
    number_card = random.randrange(1,14)
    cards = choice(suit_card), (number_card)


def getDecision():
    getDecision = raw_input("What will you do? \n - Hit \n - Stand")
    if getDecision == "Hit":
        return hit()
    elif getDecision == "Stand":
        return stand()

def hit():
    return cardGenerator()

def stand():
    return opponentphase()

def raise_bet():
    raise_amount = input("How much will you bet?")
    total_pot = 0 + raise_amount


def main():
    maingame()

main()
```

The problem is in maingame(). is return cardGenerator effectively calling the function? Not sure why I can't index a value from a list in the string formatting, when I run as of now it doesn't return anything.

Sorry if things are unclear, I'm really bad at articulating what I'm trying to explain

Comment: Realize that `return` stops execution of `maingame` so that the following `print` statement is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `maingame()`, you are returning the result of `cardGenerator()`(which is `None` because it is not returning anything), so your method `maingame()` never reaches the `print` statement. I think you could do these modifications:

```
def maingame():
    done = False
    cards = cardGenerator()
    print "{0:>4} {01:>18} {02:>20} {03:>18}".format("Player Money", (cards[0], cards[1]), "CPU Cards", "CPU Money")
```

and **return** `cards` in `cardGenerator()`, so you can use it in `maingame()`

```
def cardGenerator():
    #Assign a random suit
    suit_card = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamond"]
    from random import choice
    #Assign a random number between 1-13 (Ace to King)
    number_card = random.randrange(1, 14)
    cards = choice(suit_card), (number_card)
    return cards
```

Note that you have never declared `opponentphase()` method (at least it is not in the code you posted).

Comment: That works for the most part, but the suit/card shows up as a list now on the table, instead of e.g. Diamonds 5.

Comment: Where? What method is displaying that?

Comment: Also, using your solution results in the player and the CPU receiving the same generated card. To alleviate that, I made two separate functions (using the same code but Player/CPU specific) and now I'm getting different values for Player and CPU. Now the new problem is that in BlackJack, each player receives two cards.... but calling the variable again results in a duplicate. (Player has 2 5 of diamonds, CPU has 2 9 of spades.)

Comment: In `maingame()`, `cards` is a tuple, you may want to print cards like this, `print "{0:>4} {01:>10} {02:>5} {03:>20} {04:>18}".format("Player Money", cards[0], cards[1], "CPU Cards", "CPU Money")
`

Comment: The last problem you described, is a separate problem, think of a possible solution first, then if you can't figure out one, post a **new** question on StackOverflow, but be sure to show research effort.